# Display custom error page instead of default error page returned by android in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, error-handling, webview

I am using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin for my webview app.
Sometimes, due to network issues, the webpage does not load and android throws an error page on the screen saying page not found or timeout error.

I need to replace the content of default error page returned by android.
I am able to capture the page not found error using onLoadError method.

Kindly guide me to change the default error page using onLoadError method.

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: onWillPop,
  child: InAppWebView(
    initialUrl: 'https://myurl.com',
    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
      webView = controller;
    },
    onLoadError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url, int i,
        String s) async {
      print('CUSTOM_HANDLER: $i, $s');
      /** instead of printing the console message i want to render a static page or display static message **/
    },
    onLoadHttpError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
        int i, String s) async {
      print('CUSTOM_HANDLER: $i, $s');
      /** instead of printing the console message i want to render a static page or display static message **/
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: I would advise you to have a read through the question guidelines and rephrase/reformat your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks I have edited my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If want to stay within the `WebView` realm, then you can just add an html file to your assets with your custom error message. But you can also just show a widget over it, using a `Stack`.

---

**Option with `Widget` on top, using `Stack`**

```
InAppWebViewController webViewController;
bool showErrorPage = false;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        InAppWebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://fail.page.asd',
          onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
            webViewController = controller;
          },
          onLoadError: (
            InAppWebViewController controller,
            String url,
            int i,
            String s
          ) async {
            print('CUSTOM_HANDLER: $i, $s');
            /** instead of printing the console message i want to render a static page or display static message **/
            showError();
          },
          onLoadHttpError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
              int i, String s) async {
            print('CUSTOM_HANDLER: $i, $s');
            /** instead of printing the console message i want to render a static page or display static message **/
            showError();
          },
        ),
        showErrorPage ? Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Text('Page failed to open (WIDGET)'),
          ),
        ) : SizedBox(height: 0, width: 0),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

void showError(){
  setState(() {
    showErrorPage = true;
  });
}

void hideError(){
  setState(() {
    showErrorPage = false;
  });
}
```

*Option replacing error page with custom html file*
*Code*

```
InAppWebViewController webViewController;
bool showErrorPage = false;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: InAppWebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://fail.page.asd',
      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
        webViewController = controller;
      },
      onLoadError: (
        InAppWebViewController controller,
        String url,
        int i,
        String s
      ) async {
        print('CUSTOM_HANDLER: $i, $s');
        /** instead of printing the console message i want to render a static page or display static message **/
        webViewController.loadFile(assetFilePath: "assets/error.html");
      },
      onLoadHttpError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
          int i, String s) async {
        print('CUSTOM_HANDLER: $i, $s');
        /** instead of printing the console message i want to render a static page or display static message **/
        webViewController.loadFile(assetFilePath: "assets/error.html");
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

*pubspec.yaml*

```
assets:
    - assets/error.html
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I have used the first option and Its working as expected but now another issue has occurred i.e web page scrolling is not smooth. I can see the font is not sharp at the time of scrolling. Is it because of the stack widget used????

Comment: I just verified running my previous code as shown in my question. There is no blurry effect while scrolling. but after i change the code to use stack widget the issue appears again.

Comment: What you can do to avoid using the stack is to re-use the code where the "showError" variable is being used by replacing the `SizedBox` with the `Webview `Widget, and removing the stack completely. This will effectively replace one for the other.