# Flutter web_view Internet Connection Off Screen How to Create with image and refresh button also

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I create a Web_View app in Flutter.code ...

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      WebView(
        initialUrl: "https://artsify.in",
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

**I Need like that ...**

[Please open this image link for demo i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7TJA.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use package for checking internet, i used [internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker/):

```
class WebviewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebviewWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebviewWidget> createState() => _WebviewWidgetState();
}

class _WebviewWidgetState extends State<WebviewWidget> {
  bool isOnline = true;
  void checkOnline() async {
    isOnline = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    checkOnline();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isOnline
        ? const WebView(
            initialUrl: "https://artsify.in",
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          )
        : Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text("Ooops, connection lost"),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        checkOnline();
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text("Try again")),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

You can use [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) to show webview too,

this package allows you to handle errors too, if you mind you can follow doc or follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121661/display-custom-error-page-instead-of-default-error-page-returned-by-android-in-f) to know how to do that

Comment: it's Not Working  Error Showing.

**( type ' NULL ' is not a subtype of type 'key')**

Comment: its not web view error, its another part of code which cause this

Comment: let me know the result :)